# Are there any Unitarian Universalist-like sects in Hinduism?

Tags: sects, vivekananda, ramakrishna

Wikipedia [defines it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarian_Universalism) as:

> **Unitarian Universalism (UU) is a liberal religion
>   characterized by a "free and responsible search for truth and
>   meaning"**. Unitarian Universalists assert no creed, but instead
>   are unified by their shared search for spiritual growth, guided by a
>   dynamic, "living tradition". Currently, these traditions are
>   summarized by the Six Sources and Seven Principles of Unitarian
>   Universalism, documents recognized by all congregations who choose to
>   be a part of the Unitarian Universalist Association. These documents
>   are 'living', meaning always open for revisiting and reworking.
>
> **Unitarian Universalist (U.U.) congregations include many atheists,
>   agnostics, and theists within their membership** - and there are U.U.
>   churches / fellowships / congregations / societies all over America -
>   as well as others around the world. The roots of Unitarian
>   Universalism lie in liberal Christianity, specifically Unitarianism
>   and universalism. Unitarian Universalists state that from these
>   traditions comes a deep regard for intellectual freedom and inclusive
>   love. Congregations and members seek inspiration and derive insight
>   from all major world religions.
>
> #### Scripture
>
> **All sources admissible, none required.** Members are free to observe their own personally-favored literature.

Does [Ramakrishna Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramakrishna_Order) count as one?

Comment: The vast mass of Hindus today, except vaishnavites ARE universalist in practice - celebrating Christmas and so forth.   There is a lot of Hindu-Muslim syncretism in Tamil Nadu - hindus would seek the help of Imams to remove spells and cure disease.  Educated liberal Hindus would draw the line at animal sacrifice - but almost every religious observance  IS accepted as a practical matter by Hindus except by one sect.  @sv.

Comment: Smartism come close - to the extent they eschew caste @sv.

Comment: @SK I don't adhere to Vaishnavism but you would neither find integrity nor consistency in conglomeration of disparate doctrines... Ancient orthodox sects are imbibed with perfect integrity & consistency that I respect... Someone once said - "You start accepting all cultures & you won't left with your own." ... Universal oneness DOES MATTER but can not happen at the cost of DHARMA. Without Dharma, universality is superficial only.

Comment: More examples: "In West Bengal on 25th December more than 99 percent people celebrating Christmas on the streets are hindus. And in churches almost sixty percent visitors are Hindus" (from Quora) 73 pct of Hindus in the US celebrate Xmas (huffington post).  Even a certain community in Tamil Nadu is increasingly finding it hard not to celebrate Pillaiyar Chaturthi - in honor of the son of "a tamasic entity who is not even a god" according to them.

Comment: Celebrating on the streets is not same as going to church and listening to sermons. It is akin to Valentine day celebrations , a religious holiday that got hijacked by Hallmark .

Comment: Well, many Hindus are at least willing to be exposed to "mlecchic vibrations" emanating from celebrtaing a "mleccha" festival.

Comment: Clearly your definition of celebration is different from mine

Comment: Quora: Tasneem Ali
Tasneem Ali, Proud Indian
Answered Dec 15, 2016

Festivals in India are about celebration, spreading cheer, joy and happiness. So yes, Muslims, a lot of them celebrate Diwali.

We light diyas, eat sweets, wish friends and relatives(who are Muslims too), burn crackers and what have you.

Answer (score 1):

Neo-Vedanta, or "default Hinduism", of the Vivekananda, Dayanand Saraswati, and Yukteswar brand, are considered to follow radical egalitarianism or unitarianism.

For example, Yukteswar writes in [*The Holy Science*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Holy_Science):

> The purpose of this book is to show as clearly as possible that there is an essential unity in all religions; that there is no difference in the truths inculcated by the various faiths; that there is but one method by which the world, both external and internal, has evolved; and that there is but one Goal admitted by all scriptures.

[Vivekananda also believed](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_2/Practical_Vedanta_and_other_lectures/The_Way_to_the_Realisation_of_a_Universal_Religion) that all religions are true, but he says that the contradictions between religions are not actually contradictory, but instead supplementary:

> If it were a fact that only one of these religions is true and all the rest are false, by this time it would have covered the whole ground. But this is not so; not one has gained all the ground.
>
> ...
>
> I believe that they are not contradictory; they are supplementary. Each religion, as it were, takes up one part of the great universal truth, and spends its whole force in embodying and typifying that part of the great truth. It is, therefore, addition; not exclusion.

[Dayanand Saraswati also supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dayananda_Saraswati) reformations such as gender equality and caste equality:

> He advocated the equal rights and respects to women and advocated for the education of all children, regardless of gender.

In fact, he overturned almost all of Hindu orthodoxy:

> Dayananda Saraswati's creations, the Arya Samaj, condemned practices of several different religions and communities, including such practices as idol worship, animal sacrifice, pilgrimages, priest craft, offerings made in temples, the castes, child marriages, meat eating and discrimination against women.

Comment: This looks like a rant than an answer. My question was specifically about **sects** not what different gurus preached on this topic.

Comment: Sect (Sampradaya) has a definite meaning in Hinduism. It has to start from God which finally reaches us thru valid Guru Paramparas. Something created by Swami Vivekananda or Dayananda or Basava any other human beings are not sects .. Even a cursory glance at the Q is enough to know that the answer is "there is no such sect" .. because every Sect have some defining scriptures that they follow.

Comment: @sv. in the question you asked if Ramakrishna order is one. So, do you want an answer for conventional denominations only or religious organizations should be considered?

Comment: @Pandya Ramakrishna Order is a sect. Ramakrishna Math is the organization. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramakrishna_Order) for the difference. I don't know what you mean by 'conventional' sects - I'm looking for any/all Hindu sects which **in practice** are UU-like. I'm not looking for quotations from different gurus, hypotheses, speculations, etc.

Comment: "My question was specifically about sects not what different gurus preached on this topic." How else to answer this other than citing the leader scholars of those sects? Like if I wanted to describe the beliefs of Advaita sect, I would cite Adi Shankaracharya. Yukteswhara and Vivekananda were leading scholars of the neo-Vedanta sect/movement of Hinduism.